# npm script command to run a script command from another package.json

Tags: npm

I have two separate projects that use npm - so I have both :
`some_base_folder/projectA/package.json` and `some_base_folder/projectB/package.json`

Each of those files has a `scripts` section in it.

If I go to `some_base_folder/projectA/` and run `npm run-script test` it executes the test command from the scripts section of `some_base_folder/projectA/package.json` as it should.

What can I put as the value of `"scripts": {test_projectA:'????'` in `some_base_folder/projectB/package.json` so that when I am in `some_base_folder/projectB/` and I run `npm run-script test_projectA` it will be 
execute the `test` script of Project A?

I tried `../projectA/npm run-script test` but it says:

```
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am running under windows 7 but would prefer a solution that would also work properly on linux.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

well it turns out to be quite simple:

```
"scripts": {
  test_projectA:"cd ../projectA && npm run-script test"
}
```

Comment: seems like the log statements from my child process are not being displayed. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: you can use `--loglevel verbose`

Comment: See also @yellowsir’s answer for a cross-package-manager solution (works with yarn as well).

Comment: simple and effective. Worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 63):

You should use [`--prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix).

```
npm run [command] --prefix path/to/your/other/folder
```

And for yarn:

```
yarn --cwd path/to/your/other/folder [command]
```

Comment: OP is trying to run this from within `package.json` not from command line

Comment: @MohamedMoselhy there's nothing stopping you from putting those commands in package.json scripts section

Answer (score 13):

I ended up using:

```js
"scripts": {
   "job": "cd ./sub && \"$npm_execpath\" run subjob",
   ...
}
```

because this also works with **yarn**.

Comment: This wound up being a significant improvement over the top-voted answer for me.  With the top-voted answer I was getting some errors about conflicting bcrypt library versions (I think because I was using the NPM libraries from where I ran the command to run the command in the other folder ... instead of its own). By using the environment variable as shown in this answer it fixed that. You should accept this answer IMHO.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for this! I’m using yarn but I didn’t want to hardcode the yarn command into my package.json, works perfectly.

Comment: sadly this no longer works as __yarn__ will forward parameters "as is" so `npm run foo -- -bar` has a different meaning then `yarn run foo -- -bar`