# One npm package that runs a Vue frontend and microservice

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

My plan is to deploy both the microservice and the web app to a [zeit now](https://zeit.co/now) server such that the web app can make /api calls to the microservice server side.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to incorporate both commands into the npm scripts object of my package.json file. Currently I just have 2 directories, both with their own package.json file, with the microservice being just an index.js with a simple microservice using `micro` and the package.json file to run it. Then, my Vue config proxies requests to /api to the microservice port running locally. My config is below. I'm using the webpack advanced vuejs template.

Is this possible to do in a deployed and built way in one package? I'm using the microservice to make authenticated API calls, as any way you slice it, the keys will be revealed if they are stored in the frontend project, which is why I've opted to use a microservice that will only run server side.

In my `config/index.js`

```
dev: {
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 8080,
    autoOpenBrowser: false,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {
        '/api': {
           target: 'http://localhost:3000',
           changeOrigin: true,
           pathRewrite:{
                "^/api": ""
            }
        }
    },
    // CSS Sourcemaps off by default because relative paths are "buggy"
    // with this option, according to the CSS-Loader README
    // (https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#sourcemaps)
    // In our experience, they generally work as expected,
    // just be aware of this issue when enabling this option.
    cssSourceMap: false
  }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "bdeo",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.4.4",
    "vue-router": "^2.7.0",
    "vuetify": "^0.16.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-add-filehash": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^1.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

package.json - microservice

```
{
  "name": "microservice",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "bdeo",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "micro",
    "dev": "micro-dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "micro": "latest",
    "node-fetch": "^1.7.3",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "micro-dev": "^1.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show both package.json's <scripts> section as well?

Answer (score 0):

For running the two scripts, ref: [SO: ...run a script command from another package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710851/npm-script-command-to-run-a-script-command-from-another-package-json)

In the main package.json,

```
scripts: {
  ...
  micro-dev: "cd ../path-to-micro-package-json && npm run micro-dev",
  dev-all: "npm run dev && npm run micro-dev"
}
```

Not sure if you need more info to create the combined deploy to zeit?